# Is it possible to "mass replace" values in excel functions?

Tags: excel

I have over 100 cells where I need to replace P$30 with P$57 in the formula bar. Is it possible to do this without going into each cell and changing it one by one?

Comment: Use Edit -> Replace. BTW this question is more appropriate for superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the command Ctrl+H.  This is the "Find and Replace" functionality built into Excel.